# Building Singly Linked List (C++), using main.cpp, node.cpp/.h, and slist.cpp/.h [var SLNode does not name a type: error]

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, nodes

I am building a singly linked list that uses main.cpp and has two other files as dependencies. One being the SLNode.cpp/.h files that has a node class, and the other being the SList.cpp/.h files that have a singly linked list class. The problem I was having was that when I try to compile, the terminal says: "In file included from SLNode.h:13:0: SList.h:31:5: error: ‘SLNode’ does not name a type     SLNode* head;"

This problem has been fixed thanks to the feedback I received in the comments section. The new issue now is that when I try to compile, the terminal gives me this error:

SList.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `SLNode::~SLNode()'

but i think that is just my bad programming and the fact that I am not writing the code right.

main.cpp(called pc18.cpp):

```
/*
 * Programming Challenge 18 - UNIT TEST
 *
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 27 oct
 *
 * References: 
 */

#include "SList.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* for unit testing -- do not alter */
template <typename X, typename A>
void btassert(A assertion);
void unittest ();

int main () {
    unittest();

    return 0;
}

/*
 * Unit testing functions. Do not alter.
 */
void unittest () {

    unsigned short utCount = 13;
    unsigned short utPassed = 0;

    cout << "\nSTARTING UNIT TEST\n\n";

    SList list;

    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.getSize() == 0);
        cout << "Passed TEST 1: default constructor (size) \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 1: default constructor (size) #\n";
    }

    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.toString() == "");
        cout << "Passed TEST 2: toString \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 2: toString #\n";
    }

    list.removeHead();
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.getSize() == 0);
        cout << "Passed TEST 3: removeHead \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 3: removeHead #\n";
    }

    list.insertHead(1);
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.getSize() == 1);
        cout << "Passed TEST 4: insertHead \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 4: insertHead #\n";
    }

    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.toString() == "1");
        cout << "Passed TEST 5: toString \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 5: toString #\n";
    }

    list.removeHead();
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.getSize() == 0);
        cout << "Passed TEST 6: removeHead \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 6: removeHead #\n";
    }

    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.toString() == "");
        cout << "Passed TEST 7: toString \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 7: toString #\n";
    }

    list.insertHead(10);
    list.insertHead(20);
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.toString() == "20,10" && list.getSize() == 2);
        cout << "Passed TEST 8: insertHead,insertHead,toString,getSize \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 8: insertHead,insertHead,toString,getSize #\n";
    }

    list.removeHead();
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.toString() == "10" && list.getSize() == 1);
        cout << "Passed TEST 9: removeHead,toString,getSize \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 9: removeHead,toString,getSize #\n";
    }

    list.insertHead(5);
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.toString() == "5,10" && list.getSize() == 2);
        cout << "Passed TEST 10: insertHead,toString,getSize \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 10: insertHead,toString,getSize #\n";
    }

    list.clear();
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.toString() == "" && list.getSize() == 0);
        cout << "Passed TEST 11: clear,toString,getSize \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 11: clear,toString,getSize #\n";
    }

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        list.insertHead(i);
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.getSize() == 1000);
        cout << "Passed TEST 12: insertHead high load \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 12: insertHead high load #\n";
    }

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        list.removeHead();
    try {
        btassert<bool>(list.getSize() == 0);
        cout << "Passed TEST 13: removeHead high load \n";
        ++utPassed;
    } catch (bool b) {
        cout << "# FAILED TEST 13: removeHead high load #\n";
    }

    cout << "\nUNIT TEST COMPLETE\n\n";

    cout << "PASSED " << utPassed << " OF " << utCount << " UNIT TEST";
    if (utCount > 1) {
        cout << "S";
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}

template <typename X, typename A>
void btassert (A assertion) {
    if (!assertion)
        throw X();
}
```

SLNode.h:

```
/*
 * SLNode.cpp
 * 
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 20 oct
 * 
 * References: 
 */

#ifndef SLNODE_H
#define SLNODE_H

class SLNode {
public:
    SLNode();

    SLNode(int contents);

    ~SLNode();

    void setContents(int newContent);

    int getContents() const;

    void setNextNode(SLNode* newNode);

    SLNode* getNextNode() const;

private:
    SLNode* nextNode;
    int contents;
};
#endif
```

SLNode.cpp:

```
/*
 * SLNode.cpp
 * 
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 20 oct
 * 
 * References: 
 */
#include "SLNode.h"
#include <iostream>

SLNode::SLNode() {
    nextNode = NULL;
    contents = 0;
}

SLNode::SLNode(int value) {
    nextNode = NULL;
    contents = value;
}

SLNode::~SLNode() {
    nextNode = NULL;
}

void SLNode::setContents(int newContent) {
    contents = newContent;
}

int SLNode::getContents() const {
    return contents;
}

void SLNode::setNextNode(SLNode* newNode) {
    nextNode = newNode;
}

SLNode* SLNode::getNextNode() const {
    return nextNode;
}
```

SList.h:

```
//SList.h

#ifndef SLIST_H
#define SLIST_H

#include "SLNode.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class SLNode;
class SList {
public:
    SList();

    ~SList();

    void insertHead(int value);

    void removeHead();

    void clear();

    unsigned int getSize() const;

    string toString() const;

private:
    SLNode* head;
    unsigned int size;
};

#endif
```

SList.cpp:

```
/*
 * SList.cpp
 *
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 26 Oct
 *
 * References:
 */

#include "SList.h"

SList::SList() {
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

SList::~SList() {
    SList::clear();
    delete head;
}

void SList::insertHead(int value) {
    head = new SLNode(value);
}

void SList::removeHead() {
    if (head != NULL) {
        delete head;            
    }
}

void SList::clear() {
    delete head;
}

unsigned int SList::getSize() const {
    return size;
}

string SList::toString() const {
    stringstream ss;
    /*
    if (head == NULL) {
        return "";    
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < (size-1); i++) {
           ss << head[i] << ", "; 
        }
        ss << head[size-1];
    }
    */
    return "hello";
}
```

Makefile:

```
# Target for programming challenge-18
# Date completed: 10-26-2015
pc18: pc18.cpp SList.cpp SList.h SLNode.cpp SLNode.h
    g++ -o challenge-18 pc18.cpp SList.cpp SLNode.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have circular includes.  slnode.h includes slist.h.  slist.h includes slnode.h, which is skipped because of the include guards.  So when the SNode name is encountered later in slist.h, that class hasn't been declared yet and you get the error.

Since the slnode.h header doesn't use anything from slist.h, don't include it.  An alternative is to use `class SList;` to forward declare the class.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I deleted the #include "SList.h" from my SLNode.h file but that just generates the error I had before, which reads:

g++ -o challenge-18 pc18.cpp SList.cpp SLNode.h
/tmp/ccudaCGs.o: In function `SList::~SList()':
SList.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `SLNode::~SLNode()'

I apologize for the format, I do not know how to format comments yet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the #include "SList.h" statement from your SLNode.h file.  It's not needed and I think that's what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your strctures are referencing each other, and the conditional compiling yo have put in means that either SList or SLNode will be defined before the other.

Chaning the include order or changing the conditional compiling will not solve it -- just move the problem around.

Instead try to make a forward declaration of your struct/class like this

```
class SLNode;
class SList {
    ....
```

and the same just before the definition of `SLNode`, do a forward declaration of `SList`..

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I took the #include "SList.h" from the SLNode.h file and forward declared  like you told me, I still get an error saying that SList.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `SLNode::~SLNode()'? do you think that may be more of a makefile issue?

Comment: That is hard to say without knowing your makefile and your modified code and includes -- you should ask a new question if you have a new problem